# Empty git_json.log file in Gitlab CE

Tags: api, gitlab

After configured setting logrotation in `gitlab.rb` file, and apply change use command `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` - `api_json.log stopped filling`.

Now it is not filled in for 4 days, access rights to the directory are available to record files (`-rw-r--r--. git git api_json.log`)

API GitLab works.
How to fix it?

Comment: May we see the relevant lines of your GitLab configuration file?

Comment: Yes, of course

`logging['svlogd_size'] = 200 * 1024 * 1024 
logging['svlogd_num'] = 10 
logging['svlogd_filter'] = "gzip" 
logging['logrotate_size'] = 200 * 1024 * 1024 
logging['logrotate_rotate'] = 10 
logging['logrotate_compress'] = "compress" 
logging['logrotate_method'] = "copytruncate" 
logging['logrotate_postrotate'] = nil 

logrotate['enable'] = true`

Comment: I don't see any issues with this configuration. Any errors with the [reconfiguration logs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html#reconfigure-logs)?

Comment: No ERROR, everywhere INFO and only one WARN "Selected systemd because systemctl shows . mount Units" in last reconfigure log

Comment: It was decided after the upgrade

Comment: What is the GitLab version?

Comment: Error was in 11.10.1, upgrade to 14.10.2 then 15.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not solved by rebooting GitLab, tried to delete the file, change permissions, nothing helped.

Solved after Gitlab upgrade from 11.10.1 to 14.10.2